# cPanel route traffic through VPN tunnel allowing me to route IPs

Tags: cpanel, iptables

I would like to be able to route an IP I have from another virtual machine to my main cPanel server to be used.

cPanel server IP is `198.51.100.1` and the other machine has `203.0.113.1` and `203.0.113.2` as an additional IP.

The end goal is to add the IP 203.0.113.1 & 203.0.113.2 inside cPanel to be used to host a website and other cPanel features. The content will remain on the main server `198.51.100.1` they will just be added as if they where additional IPs inside cPanel.

How am I able to route these IP through a VPN tunnel to `198.51.100.1` keeping in mind I still need to be able to use `198.51.100.1`